# Firefox is blocking Facebook, Twitter embeded widgets

Tags: firefox, ubuntu-14.04, firefox-sync

I can't see any Twitter or Facebook embed widget like Comments or embedded Twits.

I have all extensions disabled. I thought it could be uBlock, then I disabled it and then uninstalled it, but no luck.

Then I "refreshed" Firefox.

Things started to work until I press "Sync Now" to get all my extensions (but disabled) back. Now the problem is there again.

What could be it?

If I restart Firefox in safe mode, things work again.

There must be something in my profile. In "Sync", I have only Plugins, Bookmarks and Preferences checked.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like even though an add-on is disabled it still causing a conflict.  You will have to add each add-on, one by one, until you find the culprit to a clean profile.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a new feature called `Tracking Protection` and can be disabled in `About:Config`